# P1105 - Differential Pressure Sensor Intake Manifold Pressure Too High (Bank 1) Mini Cooper R56

Tags: obd-ii, mini-cooper, manifold-absolute-pressure-sensor

I am having exact issue as mentioned in this [forum](https://www.northamericanmotoring.com/forums/r56-hatch-talk-2007/277508-p1105-differential-pressure-sensor-intake-manifold-pressure-too-high-bank-1-a.html) Trying to see if this can be answered in SE.

> I have the following: Mini One 2007 R56 with 130,000 miles on the
> clock.
>
> I been experiencing rough idle when waiting at the traffic lights for
> more than 30 second. Soon upon I receive a flashing CEL indicating a
> hard misfire. However the rough idle only occur occasionally. Other
> than the outline problem above the car runs fine & accelerates on
> demand.
>
> I manage to pull the following code from the OBD II reader: P1105 -
> Differential Pressure Sensor Intake Manifold Pressure Too High (Bank
> 1)
>
> A little research suggest replacing the MAP sensor, but I was
> wondering if there is other task I need to perform before narrowing it
> down to just the sensor. Plus can the sensor be cleaned? Also anybody
> has any idea where the sensor is location? (I'm a novice mechanic )

The code description can be found in [MiniMania](https://www.minimania.com/Mini_Cooper_Gen_II_OBDII_Powertrain_Codes)

---

Based on @FDryer's comment, I tested absolute barometric pressure, and it remains at 99 kPa regardless, not sure if I selected the right PID for MAP sensor also the Fuel Rail pressure is 0 kPa so I suspect bad rail pressure as well?:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't think you can clean a MAP sensor. I think once they start having issues it's replacement time. It should be located in the intake tract after the throttle body, but I don't know for sure. Is the "One" the same as the Cooper we have here in the States?

Comment: To ID your map sensor, try online parts places like rockauto, BMW or other parts distributors for images. Some vehicle manufacturers have online parts diagrams to show where parts are located.

One way to determine if your map sensor is faulty or not is to observe output signal at ignition on time (engine off). Output should be the same as ambient barometric pressure in your area from local weather reporting. Any conversion needed can be found online (kpa to in hg, etc). The value should drop as engine vacuum lowers manifold pressure.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 yes, I actually have R56 with N12 engine (US model), not "One", and I believe "One" is perhaps only sold in UK

Comment: @FDryer I have updated the question, please see it. Looks like Absolute Barometric Pressure is stuck at 99 kPa so could be faulty sensor

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I did clean the MAP sensor using MAF sensor cleaner and isopropyl alcohol, it was located on intake manifold.

Comment: @user0193 - Sorry, I didn't mean you *can't* clean the MAP ... I mean, I don't think it will do you any good.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 ahan, makes sense.

Comment: 99 kpa = 29.2347 in hg. Is this @ignition ON, engine OFF time? If yes, this value should match local barometric pressure (did you find local baro pressure at the time you measured  29.2347 as map value should closely match baro pressure. If good then what's the value with engine idling? Vacuum should change 99 kpa to 50-64 kpa/15-18 in hg. If idle rpm value doesn't change, either the sensor failed or wiring/connection damage occurred.

Comment: @FDryer 99 kpa = 29.2347 in hg is engine ON / running. Today I just got it scanned by professional scanner tool, looks like Mini N12 (non-S) engine dont have rail pressure sensor thats why I got no value. The mechanic said it could be MAP sensor or just air leakage as well causing sensor values to saturate. I have updated the question with the codes he provided. He suggested to remove/unplug the wire for MAP sensor and see what happens

Comment: Your map sensor is faulty according to your last reply. In order to understand map sensor operation and values, simply connect your reader to any other car with EFI and observe the map sensor output. Values start at local barometric pressure from weather sources at ignition ON/engine OFF time and after starting up with engine idling. You should see two different values; ignition on - same as local baro pressure, lower with engine idling.